# Kotlin: Shuffle answers in multiple choice quiz

Tags: android, kotlin, shuffle

I've created a multiple choice quiz in Kotlin. I want to shuffle the answers within each question and identify the new position of the correct answer to check against the answer submitted by the user. I've created a function to shuffle but am not sure how to correctly implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Object with questions

```
object ConstantsAnalysis {
        const val TOTAL_CORRECT: String = "total_correct"
        const val TOTAL_OPP: String = "total_opp"
        fun getQuestions3(): ArrayList<Questions3> {
            val questionList = ArrayList<Questions3>()
            val q1 = Questions3(1, null, "On a graph, the horizontal line along which data are plotted is the _____",
                "y axis", "x axis", "origin", "quadrant", 2, R.string.Jones_1997, null)

            val q2 = Questions3(2, null, "On a graph, the vertical line along which data are plotted is the _____",
                "y axis", "origin", "x axis", "quadrant", 1, R.string.Jones_1997, R.string.Holmes_1977)

            questionList.addAll(listOf(q1, q2))
            questionList.shuffle()
            return questionList
        }
    }
```

Data Class

```
data class Questions3(val id: Int, val image: Int?, val question: String, val option1: String, val option2: String, val option3: String, val option4: String, val correctAnswer: Int, val dialogBox: Int?, val dialogBox2: Int?)
```

Questions Activity

```
class QuestionsActivityAnalysis : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var mCurrentPosition:Int = 1
    private var mQuestionsList:ArrayList<Questions3>? = null
    private var mSelectedOptionPosition:Int = 0
    private var mCorrectAnswers: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions_analysis)
        val actionBar = supportActionBar
        actionBar!!.title = "Assessment"
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        mQuestionsList = getQuestions3()
        setQuestion()
        radio_button1.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button2.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button3.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button4.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
fun shuffleOptions(questions3: List<Questions3>): List<Questions3> {
        val result: MutableList<Questions3> = mutableListOf()
        for (q in questions3) {
            val options = listOf(q.option1, q.option2, q.option3, q.option4)
            val shuffledOptions = options.shuffled()
            val newCorrectAnswer = shuffledOptions.indexOf(options[q.correctAnswer])
            result.add(Questions3(q.id, q.image, q.question, shuffledOptions[0], shuffledOptions[1], shuffledOptions[2], shuffledOptions[3], newCorrectAnswer, q.dialogBox, q.dialogBox2))
        }
        return result
    }

private fun defaultOptionsView(){
    val options = ArrayList<TextView>()
    options.add(0, radio_button1)
    options.add(1, radio_button2)
    options.add(2, radio_button3)
    options.add(3, radio_button4)

}
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.radio_button1 -> {
                selectedOptionView(radio_button1, 1)
            }
            R.id.radio_button2 -> {
                selectedOptionView(radio_button2, 2)
            }
            R.id.radio_button3 -> {
                selectedOptionView(radio_button3, 3)
            }
            R.id.radio_button4 -> {
                selectedOptionView(radio_button4, 4)
            }
            R.id.btn_submit -> {
                if (mSelectedOptionPosition == 0) {
                    if (radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId == -1 && btn_submit.isPressed && btn_submit.text == "SUBMIT") {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select an answer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                    } else {
                        radio_group.clearCheck()
                        mCurrentPosition++
                    }
                    when {
                        mCurrentPosition <= mQuestionsList!!.size -> {
                            setQuestion()
                        }
                        else -> {
                            val intent = Intent(this, ResultsActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra(ConstantsAnalysis.TOTAL_CORRECT, mCorrectAnswers)
                            intent.putExtra(ConstantsAnalysis.TOTAL_OPP, mQuestionsList!!.size)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    val questions3 = mQuestionsList?.get(mCurrentPosition - 1)
                    if (questions3!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionPosition) {
                        answerView(mSelectedOptionPosition, R.drawable.incorrect_option_border_bg)
                        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        when {
                            questions3.dialogBox!=null && questions3.dialogBox2!=null -> {
                                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Test \n\n" + getString(questions3.dialogBox) + "\n\n" + getString(questions3.dialogBox2))
                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                    .setNegativeButton("Close") { dialog, id -> dialog.cancel()
                                    }
                                val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
                                alert.show()
                            }
                            questions3.dialogBox!=null && questions3.dialogBox2 == null -> {
                                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Test \n\n" + getString(questions3.dialogBox))
                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                    .setNegativeButton("Close") { dialog, id -> dialog.cancel()
                                    }
                                val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
                                alert.show()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        mCorrectAnswers++
                    }
                    answerView(questions3.correctAnswer, R.drawable.correct_option_border)
                    if (mCurrentPosition == mQuestionsList!!.size) {
                        btn_submit.text = "FINISH"
                    } else {
                        btn_submit.text = "NEXT QUESTION"
                    }
                    mSelectedOptionPosition = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks ok at first glance. Are there any problems with the code?

Comment: It runs but doesn't shuffle the options.

Comment: I have a quiz app. When I set a question I set the answer to a variable. I then create a list programmatically of the possible answers which includes the right one, shuffle the list (so the order varies) and apply them to the buttons. Then within my button listeners I simply check the button text to the variable to understand if their answer matched the correct answer. When you shuffle you don't need a new variable you can call the list you already created using options.shuffle()

Answer (score 1):

There is a good way to do that by separating the `Question` and `Answer` to separate objects.
What I mean is that instead of the question has a list of strings as answers, you can put a list of Custom Answer objects

To be more specific you have to create an answer class like this one.

#### Answer.kt

```kotlin
data class Answer(
        val answer: String,
        val isCorrect: Boolean,
        // You can add other attributes
)
```

Then You have to change your `Question` class to be like this

#### Question.kt

```kotlin
data class Question(
        val id: Int,
        val image: Int?,
        val answers: MutableList<Answer>, // or You can add them as 4 separate answer objects
        val dialogBox: Int?,
        val dialogBox2: Int?
)
```

Then it will be easier to shuffle and identify the correct answer by getting the answer that the user selected and call

```kotlin
if (answer.isCorrect()){
   // Whatever
}
```

By implementing that, shuffling will be as easy as

```kotlin
val question = Question( /* Question Defenition*/)
question.answers.shuffle()
```

### Edit

For example you can define the question like this in your MainActivity `onCreate`

```kotlin
val answersList1 = mutableListOf(
    Answer("answer1", false),
    Answer("answer2", false),
    Answer("answer3", true), // This is the correct answer
    Answer("answer4", false),
)
val question1 = Question(
    id = 0,
    image = R.drawable.image,
    answers = answersList,
    dialogBox = 1,
    dialogBox2 = 2
)
```

Then rename your RadioButtons by changing their text property or if you are using `TextViews` you can rename them as well.

```kotlin
radio_button0.text = answersList1[0].answer
radio_button1.text = answersList1[1].answer
// add 4 radio buttons
```

Then in your `onClick` callback you can trigger the click and identify the correct answer like this

```kotlin
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v?.id) {
        R.id.radio_button0 -> {
            if (answersList1[0].isCorrect)
            // the answer is correct
        }
        R.id.radio_button1 -> {
            if (answersList1[1].isCorrect)
                // the answer is correct
                // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the data class Answer() do I need to include four val answers and four booleans? (i.e. `val answer1: String, val isCorrect: Boolean, val answer2: String, val isCorrect: Boolean`, etc.) How would I change `object QuestionsAnalysis` to accomodate these changes? How do I reference the correct answer in the `Questions Activity`?

Comment: I will try to make a simple example

Comment: I appreciate you writing this out. Unfortunately I have around 100 questions and would prefer not to rewrite them all to separate questions from answers. Is there a way to use the shuffle function I have in my code or maybe set the correct answer to a string so I wouldn't have to worry about the correct option position?